# Json Data does not displaying in Table Format while using Entity Framwork in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc-4, angular-ui-router

I am trying to display json data display in html table data i am using Entity framework and that data while using Debugging i am able to get json format but am not able to display this data in table am using MVC with Angular JS.
help me.

this is the Controller code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CRUDOpration.Models;

namespace CRUDOpration.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeConController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public JsonResult GetAll_EmployeeData()
        {
            using (Rakesh_SinghEntities Re = new Rakesh_SinghEntities())
            {
                List<Emp1> eMp = Re.Emp1.ToList();
                return Json(eMp,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        public JsonResult Get_EmployeeByID(string ID)
        {
            using (Rakesh_SinghEntities Re = new Rakesh_SinghEntities())
            {
                int EmpId = int.Parse(ID);
                return Json(Re.Emp1.Find(EmpId), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        public string Insert_Employee(Emp1 emp)
        {
            if(emp!=null)
            {
                using (Rakesh_SinghEntities Re = new Rakesh_SinghEntities())
                {
                    Re.Emp1.Add(emp);
                    Re.SaveChanges();
                    return "Employee Data Add Successfully";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "Employee Insertion Faild! Please Try Again";
            }
        }
        public string Delete_Employee(Emp1 Emp)
        {
            if (Emp != null)
            {
                using (Rakesh_SinghEntities Obj = new Rakesh_SinghEntities())
                {
                    var Emp_ = Obj.Entry(Emp);
                    if (Emp_.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached)
                    {
                        Obj.Emp1.Attach(Emp);
                        Obj.Emp1.Remove(Emp);
                    }
                    Obj.SaveChanges();
                    return "Employee Deleted Successfully";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "Employee Not Deleted! Try Again";
            }
        }
        public string Update_Employee(Emp1 emp)
        {
            if(emp!=null)
            {
                using (Rakesh_SinghEntities Re = new Rakesh_SinghEntities())
                {
                    var Emp_ = Re.Entry(emp);
                    Emp1 empobj = Re.Emp1.Where(x => x.EmpId == emp.EmpId).FirstOrDefault();
                    empobj.EmpName = emp.EmpName;
                    empobj.EmpJob = emp.EmpJob;
                    empobj.EmpSalary = emp.EmpSalary;
                    empobj.DeptId = emp.DeptId;
                    Re.SaveChanges();
                    return "Employee Data Update Successfully";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "Employee Not Updated! Please Try Again";
            }

        }

    }
}
```

this is my .cshtml code

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/MyEmployeeData.js"></script>

<h2>Index</h2>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="GetAllData()" class="divList">
        <p class="divHead">List of Employee</p>
        <table cellpadding="12" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <b>EmpID</b>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <b>EmpName</b>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <b>EmpJob</b>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <b>EmpSalary</b>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <b>DeptId</b>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <b>Actions</b>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="Emp in Emp1">
                <td>
                    {{Emp.EmpId}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{Emp.EmpName}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{Emp.EmpJob}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{Emp.EmpSalary}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{Emp.DeptId}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Update" ng-click="UpdateEmployee(Emp)" />
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" ng-click="DeleteEmployee(Emp)" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <h2>
                        <span id="spn">Add New Employee</span>
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" ng-model="EmpName">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Job:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputjob" placeholder="Job" ng-model="EmpJob">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Salary:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputsalary" placeholder="Salary" ng-model="EmpSalary">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Department</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDept" placeholder="Department" ng-model="DeptId">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <input type="button" id="btnSave" class="form-control btn btn-info" value="Submit" ng-click="Insert_Employee()" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @Html.Hidden("EmpID_")
</div>
```

And this is my .JS file

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    debugger;
    $scope.Insert_Employee = function () {
        var Action = document.getElementById("btnSave").getAttribute("value");
        if (Action == "Submit") {
            $scope.Employe = {};
            $scope.Employe.EmpName = $scope.EmpName;
            $scope.Employe.EmpJob = $scope.EmpJob;
            $scope.Employe.EmpSalary = $scope.EmpSalary;
            $scope.Employe.DeptId = $scope.DeptId;
            $http({
                method: "post",
                url: "http://localhost:5718/EmployeeCon/Insert_Employee",
                datatype: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify($scope.Employe)
            }).then(function (response) {
                alert(response.data);
                $scope.GetAllData();
                EmpName = "";
                EmpJob = "";
                EmpSalary = "";
                DeptId = "";
            })
        } else {
            $scope.Employe = {};
            $scope.Employe.EmpName = $scope.EmpName;
            $scope.Employe.EmpJob = $scope.EmpJob;
            $scope.Employe.EmpSalary = $scope.EmpSalary;
            $scope.Employe.DeptId = $.scope.DeptId;
            $scope.Employe.EmpId = document.getElementById("EmpID_").value;
            $http({
                method: "post",
                url: "http://localhost:5718/EmployeeCon/Update_Employee",
                datatype: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify($scope.Employe)
            }).then(function (response) {
                alert(response.data);
                $scope.GetAllData();
                EmpName = "";
                EmpJob = "";
                EmpSalary = "";
                DeptId = "";
                document.getElementById("btnSave").setAttribute("value", "Submit");
                document.getElementById("btnSave").style.backgroundColor = "cornflowerblue";
                document.getElementById("spn").innerHTML = "Add New Employee";
            })
        }
    }
    $scope.GetAllData = function () {
        $http({
            method: "get",
            url: "http://localhost:5718/EmployeeCon/GetAll_EmployeeData"
        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.employees = response.data;
        }, function () {
            alert("Error Occur");
        })
    };
    $scope.DeleteEmployee = function (Emp) {
        $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "http://localhost:5718/EmployeeCon/Delete_Employee",
            datatype: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(Emp)
        }).then(function (response) {
            alert(response.data);
            $scope.GetAllData();
        })
    };
    $scope.UpdateEmployee = function (Emp) {
        document.getElementById("EmpID_").value = Emp.EmpId;
        $scope.Employe.EmpName = Emp.EmpName;
        $scope.Employe.EmpJob = Emp.EmpJob;
        $scope.Employe.EmpSalary = Emp.EmpSalary;
        $scope.Employe.DeptId = Emp.DeptId;

        document.getElementById("btnSave").setAttribute("value", "Update");
        document.getElementById("btnSave").style.backgroundColor = "Yellow";
        document.getElementById("spn").innerHTML = "Update Employee Information";
    }
})
```

this is Class where i wrote property.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Emp1
    {
        public int EmpId { get; set; }
        public string EmpName { get; set; }
        public string EmpJob { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> EmpSalary { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DeptId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `GetAllData` function saves the data in the `employees` variable.

Try changing `<tr ng-repeat="Emp in Emp1">` to `<tr ng-repeat="Emp in employees">`

Comment: my class name is Emp1 then how can i write employee sir?

Comment: Class name shouldn't matter here. In the `ng-repeat`, you are trying to iterate over the list of employees retrieved by the `GetAllData` function. The `GetAllData` function has the following line: `$scope.employees = response.data;` which stores the response in `$scope.employees`. So, you need to iterate over `employees` and not `Emp1`

Comment: Yeah i Got my Correct Result According to your Idea.
Thanks you so much.

Comment: sorry i need one more help when i want to update the record its not updating can you help me please?

Comment: It is best to keep the question limited to a single issue. I'd recommend creating a separate question for update bug.